# watchkit: sleep -- can the isIdleTimer be changed/disabled?

Tags: watchkit, sleep, idle-timer

I'm looking for an equivalent to the following iOS option:  `UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true`
That is, I'd like my Watch application to stay alive longer than the quick "sleep"/idle time that gets triggered when you don't move your wrist.

Comment: Well structured questions get more attention on Stack-overflow. This question is on the borderline between  discussion and QA. I suggest you edit this question and provide as much context, ie SDK version for example and try and make the question completely specific. See here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Its not perfect -- the watch will still sleep with inactvity, but this extension does slow it down by tricking the watch do ignore a 'wrist-down' or 'wrist-move' motion: Add the WKExtension **inside** one of your @IBActions:

```
@IBAction func mySlidefunction(){
   // ... etc ...
   WKExtension.shared().isAutorotating = true;
   // ... etc ...
}
```